# Keras:Vgg16 -- Error in `decode_predictions'

Tags: python-2.7, classification, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to perform an image classification task using a pre-trained VGG16 model in Keras. The code I wrote, following the instructions in the [Keras application page](https://keras.io/applications/), is:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
img_path = './train/cat.1.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

features = model.predict(x)
(inID, label) = decode_predictions(features)[0]
```

which is quite similar to the code shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910617/keras-valueerror-decode-predictions-expects-a-batch-of-predictions) already asked in the forum. But in spite of having the *include_top* parameter as *True*, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg16-keras-classifier.py", line 14, in <module>
    (inID, label) = decode_predictions(features)[0]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because (according to a function definition which might be found [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py)) a function `decode_predictions` returns a triple `(class_name, class_description, score)`. This why it claims that there are too many values to unpack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Turns out, if you just use `result=decode_predictions(features)` then the output actually is within another array, like `[[(a1,b1,c1),...,(a5,b5,c5)]]`. So, to get the top result, one has to write, `decode_predictions(features)[0][0]`