# Keras: ValueError: decode_predictions expects a batch of predictions, NEW

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using keras' pre-trained model VGG16, following this link: [Transfer learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-transfer-learning-when-developing-convolutional-neural-network-models/) I'm trying predict content of an [image](https://3qeqpr26caki16dnhd19sv6by6v-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/dog.jpg):

```
# example of using a pre-trained model as a classifier
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
# load an image from file
image = load_img('dog.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
# convert the image pixels to a numpy array
image = img_to_array(image)
# reshape data for the model
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
# prepare the image for the VGG model
image = preprocess_input(image)
# load the model
model = VGG16()
# predict the probability across all output classes
yhat = model.predict(image)
# convert the probabilities to class labels
label = decode_predictions(yhat)
# retrieve the most likely result, e.g. highest probability
label = label[0][0]
# print the classification
print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2]*100))
```

Full Error Output:

> ValueError: `decode_predictions` expects a batch of predictions (i.e. a 2D array of shape (samples, 2622)) for V1 or (samples, 8631) for V2.Found array with shape: (1, 1000)

This is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910617/keras-valueerror-decode-predictions-expects-a-batch-of-predictions) to a seemingly similar question on SO.

Any comments and suggestions highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and it works properly. Since I do not have your image dog.jpg I used a color jpg image of an Afghan dog and the network identified it correctly as an Afghan Hound. So I suspect there is something amiss with your image. Yhat is a 1 X 1000 array as expected.  Ensure you image is an rgb image.

Comment: thank you for your help. 
I was running this in Colab and had earlier tests code where in different cell i have imported for:

from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
from keras_vggface.utils import preprocess_input
from keras_vggface.utils import decode_predictions

That was the reason for the error....

Comment: I suspected something was wrong in inputting the image.  If satisfied please accept answer. Polish guy here too!

Comment: I have realised what is going on as soon as a read your replay. Thank you Gerry P from the Polish people.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. I was running this in Colab and had earlier tests code where in different cell i have imported for:

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace 
from keras_vggface.utils import preprocess_input 
from keras_vggface.utils import decode_predictions
```

That was the reason for the error.... –